# Term for "something that pursues goals"

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

Is there a word for "something that pursues goals"?

Animals pursue goals, but so do humans, and we can even say that bacteria pursue goals, or even governments and companies.

Comment: **Never** consult a thesaurus when writing your résumé, especially not our local elugameosaurus here.

Comment: Is this comment in the right place? I'm wondering because there's no reference to a résumé in the question.

Answer (score 1):

An important concept here is that of [teleology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teleology) and [telos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telos):

> Teleology or finality is a reason or explanation for something as a function of its end, purpose, or goal.
>
> ---
>
> A telos (from the Greek τέλος for "end", "purpose", or "goal") is an end or purpose, in a fairly constrained sense used by philosophers such as Aristotle.

Per Merriam-Webster, the adjective form is [telic](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/telic):

> 1. Tending toward an end or outcome
> 2. Characterizing an action that moves toward a goal

So you could describe the *telos* of animals, humans and bacteria, or describe them as *telic*. Or you could be studying the *teleology* of them.

Comment: I actually thought of that too, but double checked with the Wiki article and figured it's a bit too broad here. It's original meaning is to describe how everthing has some ultimate purpose. Wiki: "Aristotle claimed that an acorn's intrinsic telos is to become a fully grown oak tree."

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Jason Bassford's 'goal-oriented'.

[***Purposive***](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/purposive?s=t) is an alternative synonym; in your context you could speak of purposive organisms.

Dictionary

> having, showing, or acting with a purpose, intention, or design.

There is a branch of psychology called [purposive behaviourism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purposive_behaviorism) which includes humans and animals. Here a quote from the Wikipedia article:

> This approach of Tolman's was first introduced in his book, Purposive
>   Behavior in Animals and Men, published in 1932. To Tolman, it was
>   obvious that all actions of behavior are goal-oriented, including
>   those for animals.The main difference between behaviorism and Tolman's
>   purposive behaviorism is that behavior is goal oriented.

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of a *noun* that means that, but the adjective, appropriately enough, is simply [**goal-directed**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/medical/goal-directed):

> [Merriam-Webster]
>   : aimed toward a goal or toward completion of a task
>   // *goal-directed* behavior

In short:

> They are *goal-directed*.

---

A less specific, but perhaps more common, adjective is [**purposeful**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/purposeful):

> [Merriam-Webster]
>   **1** : having a purpose: such as
>   **a** : MEANINGFUL
>   // *purposeful* activities
>   **b** : INTENTIONAL
>   // *purposeful* ambiguity

Comment: Related: _goal-oriented_

Answer (score 0):

***seeker***

Use cases:

> the Doppler frequency difference's fomulas are given based on its relationship with the flight altitude, relative velocity and range between **target and seeker**.
>   (*Effect of target parameters on pulse Doppler radar seeker …* in Sys Engg & Elec.,2012. [Abstract](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/287047991_Effect_of_target_parameters_on_pulse_Doppler_radar_seeker_under_the_conditions_of_low-altitude_multipath))

See also:

> …*R* denotes the spatial distance between **target and seeker**; …
>   (Gaoxiang Zou, *A Modified Four Path Method for Calculating Coupling Field of Super-Low Altitude Aircraft Target*, J. Comp. & Comm. VI 12, 2018. [Abstract](https://file.scirp.org/Html/89439_89439.htm))

and

> Minor plane differences between **target and seeker** will be corrected during boost flight by the Titan 2.
>   (Aviation Week & Space Technology, Vol. 79, 1963, p.195. [Extract](https://books.google.com/books?id=ogw-AQAAIAAJ&dq=%22differences%20between%20target%20and%20seeker%22), Google Books)